# How to approach the problem of finding an isometry between two applicable surfaces?

Tags: differential-geometry, isometry

As a consequence of Gauss's Theorema Egreguim, a nessecary condition for two surfaces to be isometric to each other is that the Gaussian curvature of corresponding points should be the same. However, this condition is not sufficient, and I read that there are surfaces fulfilling this criterion that are not globally isomertic to each other. I'm willing to learn a bit more about the sufficient conditions of applicability of two surfaces to each other, as well as the different approaches to finding an explicit transformation of a given surface into another surface.

As an example, Wikipedia article [Catenoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenoid) mentions such an explicit formula, for the transformation of the catenoid into an helicoid. First of all, the parametric representation of a catenoid whose axis of symmetry is $z$ is:

$$z=v$$
$$x=c\cdot \mathbb{cosh}(v/c) \mathbb{cos} u$$
$$y=c\cdot \mathbb{cosh}(v/c) \mathbb{sin} u$$

and by using the following transformation (called "helicoid transformation" in the wikipedia article):

$$x(u,v)=\mathbb{cos\theta\cdot sinhv\cdot sin} u + \mathbb{sin\theta\cdot coshv\cdot cos} u$$
$$y(u,v)=\mathbb{-cos\theta\cdot sinh v\cdot cos} u +\mathbb{sin\theta\cdot coshv\cdot sin} u$$
$$z(u,v)=u\mathbb{cos}\theta+v\mathbb{sin}\theta$$

one gets a family of surfaces isometric to the initial catenoid (with the continous parameter for this family of surfaces being $\theta$); an helicoid corresponds to the value $\theta =\frac{\pi} {2}$.

So my question is really about understanding more on the principles behind such mappings. Good references that discuss this particular problem will also be blessed!